# Extracting array elements from JSON (javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, element

I'm trying to manipulate JSON data received from an API url (this is my first time handling this type of work)

The following function returns a promise of a 20 element array:

```
const articles = () => {
return fetch(url)
.then(res => res.json())
.then(post => post.articles);
};
```

Console view:

[image]

Now, I'd like to extract the elements from the array - I tried something like:

> articles()[0].name

but this doesn't work and I'm not sure of an alternative way to go about this? Appreciate your help. Thanks

Comment: Try to define variable and then assign the returned response to that variable!

Comment: Once you've parsed it (`response.json()`), it's not JSON, it's just an array. JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More here.)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `articles` fucntion returns a promise. You have to *consume* the promise ([more on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises)):

```
articles().then(articleArray => {
    console.log(articleArray);
});
```

or within an [`async` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function):

```
const articleArray = await articles();
console.log(articleArray);
```

---

Side note: Your `fetch` code is missing a check for HTTP success (HTTP failure isn't a rejection). You're **by far** not the only person who misses out this check, so much so that [I've written a post on my anemic blog about it](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2018/06/common-fetch-errors.html). With the check:

```
const articles = () => {
    return fetch(url)
    .then(res => {
        if (!res.ok) {
            throw new Error("HTTP error " + res.status);
        }
        return res.json();
    })
    .then(post => post.articles);
};
```

Comment: Thanks - noted on the HTTP success check.
Rather than printing the array list to console, is it possible to store the received array as a separate array variable? This way I can easier manipulate it like array[0].author etc.

I did try to assign articles().then(res => res) to array variable but it still returned the promise

Comment: @Jat90 - You can do that, but in general it doesn't make sense to. Just use the array within the `then` callback. If you save it to some variable the `then` callback closes over, at some point you **are** going to try to use it before the ajax call has completed, see [this question's answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) for more on that point.